# Change container size when there is more text in css/react

Tags: html, css

I'm making a social media network and when the text is longer (I added a max of 1000 characters), I want the container to fit to that size and not that when a post contains few text its just a big space with nothing.

I tried using vh but that didn't work I also tried using percentages and when using js for I don't know how to use the amount of characters to get the desired size since not every letter is the same size (m is bigger than i).

Here is my css:

```
.postImage {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
}

.post:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.postImage:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post .card-header {
  flex: 20%;
  border-bottom: 1 px solid lightgray;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-100);
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  color: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.post .body {
  flex: 60%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: var(--color-surface-40);
  color: white;
}

.post .footer {
  flex: 20%;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-100);
  color: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

This is the html:

```
<div>
      {[...listOfPosts].reverse().map((value, key) => {
        return (
          <div
            className={value.postImage ? "postImage" : "post"}
            onClick={() => {
              navigate(`/post/${value.id}`);
            }}
          >
            <div className="card-header"> {value.posttitle} </div>
            <div className="body">{value.posttext}</div>
            {value.postImage ? (
              <Image
                style={{ width: "100%", height: 200 }}
                source={{
                  uri: `https://server.fillyourfreetime.com/${value.postImage}`,
                }}
              />
            ) : (
              <div></div>
            )}
            <div className="footer">{value.username}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

When I just add the 100 characters text and not do anything with the code the posts for some reason overlap and don't make room for each other.

I tried using things inside css to change it like the size and with vh and percentages.

I saw some posts to change the text size but that didn't work and I want all the text to be the same size

Thanks in advance